# Laravel -listar productos con el stock de sus sucursales traidos desde otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Soy nuevo en esto, gracias por su ayuda! tengo un sistema POS hecho con Laravel, tengo tres tablas

products: id, nombre, precio.
location: id, nombre.
stock: id, product_id, location_id, qty_available.

Necesito listar los productos con datos de las tres tablas y que me los muestre asi:

```
|Producto|Precio |sucursal 1|sucursal 2|sucursal 3|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|reloj pro |25.000 | 4.000000|8.000000 | 0.000000 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

donde sucursal 1,2 y 3 son los nombres de las sucursales y muestra el stock de cada una.
Ahora tengo esto en el controller

````
```$products = Variation::join('products as p', 'variations.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
                ->join('product_locations as pl', 'pl.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
         

   ->leftjoin(
                    'variation_location_details AS VLD',
                    function ($join) use ($location_id) {
                        $join->on('variations.id', '=', 'VLD.variation_id');

                        //Include Location
                        if (!empty($location_id)) {
                            $join->where(function ($query) use ($location_id) {
                                $query->where('VLD.location_id', '=', $location_id);
                                
                                $query->orWhereNull('VLD.location_id');
                            });
                            ;
                        }
                    }
                )
                        ->where('p.business_id', $business_id)
                        ->where('p.type', '!=', 'modifier')
                        ->where('p.is_inactive', 0)
                        ->where('p.not_for_selling', 0)
                        ->where(function ($q) use ($location_id) {
                            $q->where('pl.location_id', $location_id);
                        });

    $products = $products->select(
                'p.id as product_id',
                'p.name',
                'p.type',
                'p.enable_stock',
                'p.image as product_image',
                'variations.id',
                'variations.name as variation',
                'VLD.qty_available',
                'variations.default_sell_price as selling_price',
                'variations.sub_sku'
            )
            ->with(['media', 'group_prices'])
            ->orderBy('p.name', 'asc')
            ->paginate(50);

    $stock_by_suc = DB::table('variation_location_details')
                 ->select('product_id', 'location_id', 'qty_available')
                 ->groupBy('location_id')                 
                 ->get();
    return view('sale_pos.partials.product_list')
                    ->with(compact('products', 'allowed_group_prices', 'show_prices', 'business_locations', 'stock_by_suc'));```
````

Y en la vista:

````
```<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ajax_view dataTable no-footer fixedHeader-locked" id="pos_detalle">
                        <thead>
                          <tr style="border-top:50px">                            
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Stock</th>
                            @foreach($business_locations as $sucursales)
                            <th>{{$sucursales->landmark}}</th>
                            @endforeach
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @forelse($products as $product)
    <tr>
       <td><div class="product_box">
                        
        {{$product->name}} 
            @if($product->type == 'variable')
                - {{$product->variation}}
            @endif
        </div></td>
            <td>₡{{$product->selling_price}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->qty_available}}</td>
            @foreach($stock_by_suc as $sucursales)
            @if($sucursales->qty_available>0)
                            <td>{{$sucursales->qty_available}}</td>
            @else
            <td></td>
            @endif
                            @endforeach
   </tr>

                            
@endforelse
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </div>```
````

Se ve algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me rompí la cabeza intentando varias formas y no se como puedo armar la tabla, probé con keys, con relaciones, etc pero nada funcionó. Gracias y perdón si la primera vez no di demasiados detalles.

Comment: Añade el código con lo que has probado, aquí no te van a hacer los deberes.

Comment: Gracias @winset , es verdad, no me di cuenta, ahi va el código: